# Difference between LIKE and NOT LIKE searching for alpha numeric data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What is the difference between these two statements as far as the results?

```
SELECT * FROM DTSEARCHER 
WHERE word LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'

SELECT * FROM DTSEARCHER 
WHERE word not LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

Comment: `NOT` it's the inverse.... it's like the `!` in IF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the first one, you will get anything that matches

in the second one, you will get the rest.